# Python - Convert string of integers to Ascii

Tags: python, nfc, raspberry-pi3

Currently I work on a project with an NFC tag reader. All data is stored in decimal values and I managed to track the data I need down and cut every special character out of it. I now want to convert it to ascii so it prints out a readable version of the data.

The variable setvar is a string and has the value "84 97 103 32 78 117 109 98 101 114 32 49"

This is the code I try to use:

```
print "ASCII value: ", ´,´.join(str(chr(c)) for c in setvar)
```

Sadly this produces an error that this function needs integers. Now my next step would be to convert my string to an array(?) and read each item of that array with a loop. Sadly I have no idea how to do that.

How to do that?

Comment: What is ``setvar``? Is it your string ``"84 97 ... 32 49"``?

Comment: Could you not just do `int(setvar.replace(" ", ""))`

Comment: @jockster not really, what you are saying is something different

Comment: You need to convert to int before you use `chr`, `...chr(int(c)...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
print ', '.join(chr(int(i)) for i in setvar.split())
```

chr will convert any integer to its alphabetical ASCII letter.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just decode the corresponding `bytes`.

```
>>> s = "84 97 103 32 78 117 109 98 101 114 32 49"
>>> bytes(map(int, s.split())).decode()
'Tag Number 1'
```

(Note that `decode` can take an optional `encoding` argument, the default value is `'utf-8'`.)

Answer (score 0):

You want to split the string, not iterate over the characters, then convert to int and then back to char:

```
In [5]: [chr(int(c)) for c in x.split(' ')]
Out[5]: ['T', 'a', 'g', ' ', 'N', 'u', 'm', 'b', 'e', 'r', ' ', '1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `setvar` is your string of integer ascii values:

```
print "ASCII value: " + ','.join(chr(int(c)) for c in setvar.split())
```

Comment: @Chris_Rands, True. Copied the code from the question without inspecting it carefully. Edited now

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
    >>> s = "84 97 103 32 78 117 109 98 101 114 32 49"
    >>> ''.join(chr(int(item)) for item in s.split())
    'Tag Number 1'
    >>>
```